# How to manually create an OAuth2AuthenticationToken

Tags: spring, spring-security

I would like to manually create an [OAuth2AuthenticationToken](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/authentication/OAuth2AuthenticationToken.html) from an OIDC access and refresh token and return it from my AuthenticationProvider, in a similar way it is done during the OAuth2 Login which is based on Authorization code flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what proved to be working for me:

```
final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = roles.stream()
        .map(r -> "ROLE_" + r)
        .map(r -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r)).collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<String, Object> claims = jwt.getClaims();
String userNameKey = clientRegistration.getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint().getUserNameAttributeName();
OidcIdToken oidcIdToken = new OidcIdToken(token.getTokenValue(), token.getIssuedAt(), token.getExpiresAt(), claims);
DefaultOidcUser user = new DefaultOidcUser(authorities, oidcIdToken, userNameKey);
return new OAuth2AuthenticationToken(user, authorities, clientRegistration.getRegistrationId());
```

Comment: thanks. this helped me to recreate the OAuth2AuthenticationToken from OKTA Jwt token

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    ...
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) {
        var tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(<enhancer>));
        configurer.tokenStore(<tokenStore>).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain);
    }
    ...
}
```

In `tokenStore` you can override accessToken and refreshToken, in `enhancer` apply manipulations to token (for example, set additional info and encode to JWT).

Comment: I would like to do this in the client - I do not want to enable the @EnableAuthorizationServer